# Chrome Native client is flagged but not working on Analytics

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

basically I've been using Google Analytics for years, on chrome, but lately I have to hit refresh every single change I make or native client blocks the content with a blank pane. I have checked flags, and it's turned on. I've checked chrome version and nothing is amis. It's making work take twice as long so hoping someone else has solved this. I'm on a macbook air, running big sur 11.6.4.